# Creating a displayable 'index' of content nodes within a path

Tags: nodes

Ok, it's been over a decade since I've worked with Drupal (primary use was for a personal blogging platform, with a bit of extra extensibility and a well developed plugin ecosystem). Sadly, most of my knowledge has escaped me, so I'm starting completely from scratch knowledge wise, and I don't know where to start.

**Summary**

I'm going to use Drupal as the platform to deliver an intranet for a small company I work for.

In order to make navigation as simple as possible, and without having to worry about themes and menus constantly - I'd like to have pages where it displays an automatically generated 'table of contents' for all the documents or items on one or more levels below it.

**Explanation**

I intend to structure and alias the content with a URL alias similar to directories in a file system, for example:

Marketing
 ⌊_ eCommerce
  ⌊_ Search Advertising
      ⌊_ Google
      ⌊_ Facebook
  ⌊_ Product Maintenance
Administration
  ⌊_ Vehicles
  ⌊_ Accounting and Finance
and so on

On the homepage, I would like to have a content block or something appropriate in the body, which displays only the L1 directories (i.e. Marketing, Administration), and that is then linked to their relevant pages (i.e. domain.com/marketing, domain.com/administration).

From there, the home pages for these L1 areas have an index that traverses and lists everything automatically at L2, L3 and so on

I hope what i'm trying to achieve has made sense, and appreciate all and any help to point me in the right direction for achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you need to do is the following:

- Create a new vocabulary ([taxonomy module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/structure-taxonomy.html))
- Insert your structure as you listed above (MArketing...etc)
- Add "[entity reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAhWiqPlKh0)" field to your content type
- Use "[views](https://www.drupal.org/docs/user_guide/en/views-concept.html)" to create list the content in "table". Make sure to use the right filters
- Some other modules might help with the interface like [menu taxonomy](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu)

You can find very good training courses for Drupal on [Drupalize.me](https://drupalize.me) [and Build a Module](https://buildamodule.com)

Comment: Thanks. I'll go ahead and re-acquaint myself with all of this, so I can get started. Greatly appreciate the constructive and useful response.